# Angular 8 not displaying array

Tags: angular

I'm working on a project that has 10 object in an array. An object will be displayed in the component html, and on every click the next object in the array will be displayed.

```
send = [ 
{"id":1,  "img":"assets/level/1.jpg"},
{"id":2,  "img":"assets/level/2.jpg"},
{"id":3,  "img":"assets/level/3.jpg"},
{"id":4,  "img":"assets/level/4.jpg"},
{"id":5,  "img":"assets/level/5.jpg"},
{"id":6,  "img":"assets/level/6.jpg"},
{"id":7,  "img":"assets/level/7.jpg"},
{"id":8,  "img":"assets/level/8.jpg"},
{"id":9,  "img":"assets/level/9.jpg"},
{"id":0,  "img":"assets/level/0.jpg"},];
```

The problem is if I go to the component html and type in the src `{{send.img}}`, it doesn't show any image.

this is my html.component

```
<div class="w3-col s12 m6 l6" id="level">
            <div id="test">
                <img class="w3-round w3-mobile" width="500" height="300" src="{{level.img}}">
                <input class=" w3-margin-top w3-mobile w3-section" id="testQue" style="width:400px; height: 50px; align-content: center" type="text">
                <button id="check" class="w3-btn w3-round w3-brown w3-margin-left w3-mobile">SUBMIT</button>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Please, how do I resolve this issue?

Comment: Because `send` is an array. You would need to specify the element of the array you were wanting to access. For example `send[0].img`

Comment: can you please add the code you tried?

Comment: I have added the code

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Arrays should be referred to using the `indexes`.

Eg:  `{{send[0].img}}` or `{{send[1].img}}`

To make it dynamic you should use [loops (ngFor is angular loop)](https://alligator.io/angular/ngfor-directive/)

You should `loop an array` and call the `objects` inside it,

You need to put into **`image tag`** to get the **image displayed** using.

**`[src]="item.img"`**

```
<div *ngFor="let item of send">
    <img [src]="item.img" alt="image not available"/>
</div>
```

**Edit: Updated code as per your question:**

**Component Code:**

```
let level;

let send = [
{"id":1,  "img":"assets/level/1.jpg"},
{"id":2,  "img":"assets/level/2.jpg"},
{"id":3,  "img":"assets/level/3.jpg"},
{"id":4,  "img":"assets/level/4.jpg"},
{"id":5,  "img":"assets/level/5.jpg"},
{"id":6,  "img":"assets/level/6.jpg"},
{"id":7,  "img":"assets/level/7.jpg"},
{"id":8,  "img":"assets/level/8.jpg"},
{"id":9,  "img":"assets/level/9.jpg"},
{"id":0,  "img":"assets/level/0.jpg"}];

currentIndex = 0;

level = send[currentIndex]

nextClicked(currentIndex) {
    this.currentIndex = this.currentIndex + 1;
    if(this.currentIndex == (this.send.length - 1)){
       this.currentIndex = 0;
    }
    this.level = this.send[this.currentIndex]
}
```

**HTML Code:**

```
<div class="w3-col s12 m6 l6" id="level">
    <div id="test">
        <img class="w3-round w3-mobile" width="500" height="300" src="{{level.img}}">
        <button class="w3-btn w3-round w3-brown w3-margin-left w3-mobile" (click)="nextClicked(currentIndex)">Next</button>
        <input class=" w3-margin-top w3-mobile w3-section" id="testQue" style="width:400px; height: 50px; align-content: center" type="text">
        <button id="check" class="w3-btn w3-round w3-brown w3-margin-left w3-mobile">SUBMIT</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: check my updated code, I have updated as per your question

Comment: The img is like a question in which if guessed correctly the next image shows, i dont want all the  image showing up at once

Comment: Nice solution @Sravan. If I click on button 11th time it will throw an error. You need to reset the currentIndex or hide the button if currentIndex reaches to the length of array.

Comment: @AliWahab, added that condition too. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

`send` is an array, so you need to run a for loop

Try like this:

```
<ng-container *ngFor="let item of send">
    {{item.img}}
</ng-container>
```